# Changing languages rapidly causes Linux to crash

Tags: kubuntu, xmonad, setxkbmap

So I'm running Xmonad on my college computer (which runs Kubuntu) and whenever I leave my desk, instead of using `x-screensaver` which is incredibly buggy and slow, I just change to another workstation, open a terminal and change language to a language which uses symbols instead of letters, and then change back using an aliased command. For example, my `.profile` has the lines

```
alias qwer="setxkbmap jp"
alias *******="setxkbmap ie"
```

where ******* is my password, using japanese characters. Changing languages seems to be much faster than running `x-screensaver`.

**The problem:**
rapidly changing languages seems to crash Linux; it just won't accept input (and it's not because the language hasn't changed back, nothing is output to the console). I can't use `Ctrl+Alt+F1..F7`, I can't "raise the elephants", anything, it just won't work. I'm just wondering, is this a known issue, and if so, is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

Even though it is a Kubuntu install? That is what I use and I do not even have gnome running.

P.S. That is a lowercase 'L' and not a '1' one.